# Uploading files to Google Cloud Storage from .Net

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

We need to find a way to upload Windows text, files at random times from random PCs. We currently do this via FTP APIs from Windows Desktop .net exe programs. Google does not appear to support this type of access - have I missed something?

The `gsutil`, Platform SDK, and other external Python tools will not work for us.

Solution needs to be built using Visual Studio for Windows Desktop. REST via .Net HTTP would be OK.

Answer (score 4):

Google Cloud Storage does not directly support FTP-based uploads.

GCS does, however, have a [.NET client library](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-dotnet/). You can certainly upload objects with that.

There are [sample apps](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dotnet-docs-samples/blob/master/storage/api/Storage/Storage.cs#L131) showing how to upload an object to GCS with that library. The key bit is:

```
    private void UploadFile(string bucketName, string localPath,
        string objectName = null)
    {
        var storage = StorageClient.Create();
        using (var f = File.OpenRead(localPath))
        {
            objectName = objectName ?? Path.GetFileName(localPath);
            storage.UploadObject(bucketName, objectName, null, f);
            Console.WriteLine($"Uploaded {objectName}.");
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm trying to avoid the Google Cloud SDK if possible - especially for the resulting programs developed. If the cloud .net API calls gsutils it won't work for me. Can the Cloud .net API be used from a windows desktop program without any dependences?

Comment: don't understand your question. It doesn't require gsutil or any other external dependencies. The NuGet package does list a few packages as dependencies, which is pretty normal.

Comment: The page for Google.Cloud.Storage.V1 says for authentication the SDK needs to be installed and a CLI command entered. Do I need to do that on all desktops the app runs?

Comment: As a convenience for developers, the client library can read your credentials from the SDK if you have it installed and are logged in. Generally your final program won't authenticate this way. Instead, it will either automatically fetch credentials if it's running in the Google Cloud, or you will attach a private key file and have it use that for authentication, or you will set up an OAuth flow for your end users to log in on their own. By no means in the CLI a requirement. For more on how it reads creds, see: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/application-default-credentials

Comment: Thank you Brandon, looks like the 'Sample Apps' link is broken? would you have a working sample that would let me upload the file from my web application to the Google Cloud Storage? Thank you!